# Getting JavaScript Error in master page using ASP.NET WEB Form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Java Script not working in Content page using ASP.NET C# and I am trying to count the character of multi-line text box below is character count code.
Getting Below error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)  Uncaught ReferenceError: txtComments is not defined(…)

Below is my code JS and Design code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function characterCounter(controlId, countControlId, maxCharlimit) {
           if (controlId.value.length > maxCharlimit)
               controlId.value = controlId.value.substring(0, maxCharlimit);
           else countControlId.value = maxCharlimit - controlId.value.length;
       }


   </script>
    <fieldset style="width: 280px;">
        <legend>Counting Remaining Characters example</legend>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" Width="280px" Rows="4" Columns="12" runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="characterCounter(txtComments, this.form.remCount, 150);"
            onkeydown="characterCounter(txtComments, this.form.remCount, 150);" /><input type="text"
                name="remCount" size="3" maxlength="3" value="150" readonly="readonly" />
        characters left
    </fieldset>
```

When I am trying to type some thing values is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `this` instead of `txtComments`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" Width="280px" Rows="4" Columns="12" runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="characterCounter(this, this.form.remCount, 150);"
            onkeydown="characterCounter(this, this.form.remCount, 150);" />
```

Comment: @the upvoter : he forgot to pass, please edit the answer

Comment: But you did not mention in your answer, please update your answer. @Leopard

Comment: @MMK what i didn't mention in asnwer ?

Comment: @Leopard : don't act like smart. be smart. Keep in mind Now only you edited the answer and replaced `txtComments` with `this`. One more point you have to add is that, the method is expecting the TextBox's ID and you are passing the whole TextBox.

Comment: @un-lucky if you see `function` OP is not accessing it by id rather directly using it.

Comment: @Leopard: yep, seems you are correctly sported. thank you

Comment: Any way working fine, thank both of you and I added this key word. @Leopard

Comment: When I will press then only changes below count value and if i will copy and past then not change why?. @Leopard

Comment: For that you have to handle `paste` event.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `this` instead for the textbox ID, because the id will changed with respect to the page name(as well as the master page name if any) since it is a server side control. Which means the calling method will looks like this :

```
onkeydown="characterCounter(this, this.form.remCount, 150);"
```

Additional note: Since you are accessing the value of the Textbox from the javascript method, you need not to pass the ID of the textbox instead of that you can pass it as TextBox. so the passing parameter would be `this` not `this.Id`. and have to say thanks to `Leopard` for pointing this;

Comment: I have five multiline textbox in a single page and I have to check for all and your means this.txtComments, i have to keep. @un-lucky

Comment: Each TextBoxes will have different ids, right? so the `this.id` will give you the corresponding id. and it is not ` this.txtComments` it would be `this.id`

Comment: Then above answer one more answer of only this means getting confuse. @un-lucky

Comment: When I will press then only changes below count value and if i will copy and past then not change why?. @un-lucky